# Is there an R function for counting the occurrence of a given substring within a string?

Tags: r

I know that for counting the occurrence of one substring I can used **str.count()**. However, this function doesn't suit my needs. To be more concrete, let's say I have the string "MSAGARRRPR" and I want to count the number that the substring "RR" appears.

`stringr::str_count(string = "MSAGARRRPR", pattern = "RR")`

will return the number 1. However, in the current example, I'm interested in counting the number of times that an "R" is followed by another "R", and that happens twice.

I have written a function to count it:

```
occurrences <- function(string, pattern){
     n <- nchar(patter)
     number_pieces <- (nchar(string) - (n - 1))
     pieces <- character(number_pieces)
     for (i in 1:number_pieces){
        pieces[i] <- substring(string, first = i, last = i + (n - 1))
     }
     output <- sum(pieces == pattern)
     return(output)
    }
```

Now, `ocurrences(string = "MSAGARRRPR", pattern = "RR")` returns the expected answer: 2

Nevertheless, I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient R function to compute it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You can use lookbehind or lookahead regex :

With positive lookbehind :

```
stringr::str_count(string = "MSAGARRRPR", pattern = "(?<=R)R")
#[1] 2

stringr::str_count(string = "MSAGARRRPRR", pattern = "(?<=R)R")
#[1] 3
```

This can also be written with positive lookahead

```
stringr::str_count(string = "MSAGARRRPR", pattern = "R(?=R)")
#[1] 2

stringr::str_count(string = "MSAGARRRPRR", pattern = "R(?=R)")
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 5):

The solutions below do not use regular expressions.  (1) generalizes to windows of greater than 2 more easily but (2) and (3) use no packages.  No regular expressions are used (if we regard a fixed match in (3) as not being a regular expression).

**1) rollapply** Split the input `x` into a vector of single characters `xs` and then apply a moving window of length 2 comparing each such window to c("R", "R") returning a logical vector.  Sum the number of TRUE values in it.

```
library(zoo)

x <- "MSAGARRRPR"
k <- 2

xs <- unlist(strsplit(x, ""))
sum(rollapply(xs, k, identical, rep("R", k)))
## [1] 2
```

**2) head/tail** We could also do it using only base R.  `xs` is from (1).

```
sum(head(xs, -1) == tail(xs, -1))
## [1] 2
```

**3) gregexpr**  This one uses `gregexpr` to return the positions of the R characters and then counts the number of times there is a difference of 1 between an R character and the next R character.  The fixed = TRUE could be omitted but we included it to ensure that it just matches on R rather than having R be a regular expression. The input `x` is defined in (1).

```
sum(diff(unlist(gregexpr("R", x, fixed = TRUE))) == 1)
## [1] 2
```